# How to make a pair wise scatterplot with singular value decomposition data

Tags: r, data-visualization

I've been trying to make a pair-wise scatterplot for the last 14 hours given data obtained from an image. The data is as follows:

```
library (imager)
library(graphics)
im <- load.image('Denny.jpg')
im
plot(im)
img=(im[,,,1]+im[,,,2]+im[,,,3])/3
img
img= apply(apply(img,1,rev))
image(img,col=grey(0:12/12))


    # See more examples at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imager/vignettes/gettingstarted.html


#####################
library(graphics)
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)

A=apply(im[,,,1],1,rev)
A
image(A)

### singular value decomposition 
svd.fit=svd(A)
svd.fit
plot(svd.fit$d)

## choose first 20 components
A.hat=svd.fit$u[,1:20]%*%diag(svd.fit$d[1:20])%*%t(svd.fit$v[,1:20])
image(A.hat)
A.hat

pairs(A.hat)
svd.fit=svd(A)

plot(svd.fit$d)

## choose first 20 components
A.hat=svd.fit$u[,1:20]%*%diag(svd.fit$d[1:20])%*%t(svd.fit$v[,1:20])
image(A.hat)
ggpairs(A.hat)
```

Any help would be very greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What is the problem here, specifically? You appear to be using the correct function(s), but you do not indicate what is the problem. Can you make your example reproducible?

Comment: The problem is that there is no plot that actually shows up after running the code ggpairs(A.hat)...It says that it is plotting but then no output ever is given.

Comment: Have you tried running examples from `?ggpairs` whether they work? If you provided a reproducible example it would take it a long way.